# Custom routing in Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework

I try to configure an additional route in Zend Framework 1 as following.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route (
    'test/route/',
    array(
        'module' => 'storefront',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index' 
    )
); 
$router->addRoute('customRoute', $route);
```

Then I try to test the route and enter the following URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8888/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/test/route/
```

I always get an error page saying:" 404 Not Found. Not Found. The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server."

My application.ini that gets loaded during the bootstrapping process looks like:

```
[bootstrap]
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Zend_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "SF_"

phpsettings.display_errors = 0
phpsettings.error_reporting = 8191
phpsettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH"/bootstrap/Bootstrap.php"

resources.frontcontroller.moduledirectory = APPLICATION_PATH"/modules"
resources.frontcontroller.defaultmodule = "storefront"
resources.frontcontroller.params.prefixDefaultModule = true
resources.frontcontroller.throwerrors = false

resources.view = ""

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = "main"

[production : bootstrap]

[development : bootstrap]
phpsettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontcontroller.throwerrors = true

[test : bootstrap]
```

For debugging I dumped all routes:

```
array (size=2)
  'default' => 
    object(Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module)[46]
      protected '_defaults' => 
        array (size=3)
          'controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
          'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
          'module' => string 'storefront' (length=10)
      protected '_values' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_moduleValid' => boolean false
      protected '_keysSet' => boolean true
      protected '_moduleKey' => string 'module' (length=6)
      protected '_controllerKey' => string 'controller' (length=10)
      protected '_actionKey' => string 'action' (length=6)
      protected '_dispatcher' => 
        object(Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard)[40]
          protected '_curDirectory' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/application/modules/storefront/controllers' (length=94)
          protected '_curModule' => string 'storefront' (length=10)
          protected '_controllerDirectory' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected '_defaultAction' => string 'index' (length=5)
          protected '_defaultController' => string 'index' (length=5)
          protected '_defaultModule' => string 'storefront' (length=10)
          protected '_frontController' => null
          protected '_invokeParams' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          protected '_pathDelimiter' => string '_' (length=1)
          protected '_response' => 
            object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)[45]
              ...
          protected '_wordDelimiter' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      protected '_request' => 
        object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http)[44]
          protected '_paramSources' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected '_requestUri' => string '/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/index.php' (length=43)
          protected '_baseUrl' => string '/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/index.php' (length=43)
          protected '_basePath' => null
          protected '_pathInfo' => string '' (length=0)
          protected '_params' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          protected '_rawBody' => null
          protected '_aliases' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_dispatched' => boolean true
          protected '_module' => string 'storefront' (length=10)
          protected '_moduleKey' => string 'module' (length=6)
          protected '_controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
          protected '_controllerKey' => string 'controller' (length=10)
          protected '_action' => string 'index' (length=5)
          protected '_actionKey' => string 'action' (length=6)
      protected '_isAbstract' => boolean false
      protected '_matchedPath' => null
  'customRoute' => 
    object(Zend_Controller_Router_Route)[5]
      protected '_translator' => null
      protected '_locale' => null
      protected '_isTranslated' => boolean false
      protected '_translatable' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_urlVariable' => string ':' (length=1)
      protected '_urlDelimiter' => string '/' (length=1)
      protected '_regexDelimiter' => string '#' (length=1)
      protected '_defaultRegex' => null
      protected '_variables' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_parts' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'test' (length=4)
          1 => string 'route' (length=5)
      protected '_defaults' => 
        array (size=3)
          'module' => string 'storefront' (length=10)
          'controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
          'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
      protected '_requirements' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_values' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_wildcardData' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_staticCount' => int 2
      protected '_isAbstract' => boolean false
      protected '_matchedPath' => null
```

I really don't know why it is not working as expected. Usually it should be an easy task. Many thanks in advance for any advice!

**Update**

For any reason Zend Framework redirects the request for the URL

```
http://localhost:8888/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/index/index/
```

to

```
http://localhost:8888/index.php
```

Probably because of a wrong/missing configuration inside my application.ini?

**Update 2: mod_rewrite log**

```
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] add path info postfix: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront -> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/test/route
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/test/route -> storefront/test/route
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'storefront/test/route'
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (4) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] RewriteCond: input='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront' pattern='-s' => not-matched
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (4) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] RewriteCond: input='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront' pattern='-l' => not-matched
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (4) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] RewriteCond: input='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront' pattern='-d' => not-matched
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] add path info postfix: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront -> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/test/route
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/test/route -> storefront/test/route
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'storefront/test/route'
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (4) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] RewriteCond: input='/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/test/route::storefront/test/route' pattern='^(/.+)(.+)::\\2$' => matched
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (5) setting env variable 'BASE' to '/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/'
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] add path info postfix: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront -> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/test/route
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/test/route -> storefront/test/route
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'storefront/test/route'
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (2) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] rewrite 'storefront/test/route' -> '/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/index.php'
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#10288b0a0/initial] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] internal redirect with /selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#102896c80/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/index.php -> index.php
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#102896c80/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#102896c80/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] RewriteCond: input='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/index.php' pattern='-s' => matched
::1 - - [04/Apr/2015:20:18:52 +0200] [localhost/sid#101001730][rid#102896c80/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/] pass through /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken, this is your address that does is not in accordance with your route

For this url `.../public/storefront/test/route/` try this route:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route (
    'storefront/test/route/', // add 'storefront/'
    array(
        'module' => 'storefront',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index' 
    )
);
```

or for this route

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route (
    'test/route/',
    array(
        'module' => 'storefront',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index' 
    )
);
```

try this url :

```
`.../public/test/route/`  /* without 'storefront/' */
```

**UPDATE**
my .htaccess is very basic:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Already tried both approaches, but none worked. Both result in the 404 Not Found issue. Do you have any idea how to debug this issue?

Comment: I define $router like this : `$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();` and your example works in me app... Is url `.../public/storefront/index/index` wroks?

Comment: I define the router the same way, but for any reason Zend Framework redirects the request for the URL http://localhost:8888/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/index/index/ to http://localhost:8888/index.php

Comment: hm... an idea. In the dumped routes you can see protected '_baseUrl' => string '/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/index.php' (length=43). Shouldn't it be '/selfstudy/zend/storefront/' or 'Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/'? I already tried it, but did not solve the issue, but I wanted to understand if my issue trace is valid.

Comment: Can you maybe share your .htaccess file?

Comment: @HH.: Hi, I update my .htaccess file. To be honnest, my test was not with module architecture, I just test the route declaration in the bootstrap an I replace `storefront` by `default`, so maybe your pb is with the use of modules, but now, I've not environnement to test it. so good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your .htaccess
use .htaccess with this content:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
>
> RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

** .htaccess is a hidden file in /public directory

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I modified my .htaccess file according to your comment and the result is already better, but still not working as expected. When I call the URL http://localhost:8888/selfstudy/zend/storefront/public/storefront/test/route the view /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/application/modules/storefront/views/scripts/main.phtml gets loaded, but /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/application/modules/storefront/views/scripts/index/index.phtml should be loaded.

Comment: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/application/modules/storefro‌​nt/views/scripts/main.phtml` is not a correct path! where is it's controller?

Comment: The controller path is /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/application/modules/storefront/controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: then you should correct main.phtml path: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/zend/storefront/application/modules/storefr‌​o‌​nt/views/scripts/index/main.phtml`